# reading from an externally hosted xml file into html table

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am trying to read from an externally hosted xml document into an html table.
i will use example xml documents.

Here is my code:

```
    <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get my CD collection</button>
    <br><br>
    <table id="demo" class="responstable"></table>

    <script>
        function loadXMLDoc() {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    myFunction(xmlhttp);
                }
             };

             xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml", false);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        function myFunction(xml) {
            var i;
            var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
            var table = "<tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>";
            var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                table += "<tr><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td></tr>";
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
        }
    </script>
```

if i change the url to just cd_catalog.xml, it works because i have the file downloaded in the same directory as well. That is not my goal though. i need to access an externally hosted XML.

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console? If so, please post that too!

Comment: Google cross site resource forgery, or CSRF. That is why resources stored on different hosts won't work. One way to circumvent this would be [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: i was not getting any errors. thank you ppeterka. i looked up JSONP and found some easy scripts to use on my server side and on my client.